# What data to send using IR to control AC or TV using C#

Tags: c#, serial-port, television, remote-control, infrared

i want to control all the electronic device in my room using for example: i want to turn my TV **on/off** if it was made by **SONY or SAMSUNG** ...
i have search a lot on **Google** and got million of articles and codes samples on how to use IR but the problem is what is the data to be sent
i want the user to be able to specify the kind (the manufacturer) of the device and be able to perform the most basic operation like Volume +/- and Channel +/- and other procedures
any help in this subject is much appreciated, thank you in advance :) **Yaser**

Comment: This is a very broad question. What have you done? Do you have any code to show us?

Comment: What you really need is a link to technical documents outlining the protocols for IR communication with these devices.  Which we don't do.  But what I've done (in the long and distant past) was simply point the remote into my IR receiver and record what it sends when you push, e.g., the off button.  Now you've got it, and you can send the exact same thing out of your emitter.  Bam.

Comment: @PoweredByOrange i'm sorry i don't have the code with me right now but i have done pretty much the same things as in these articles
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18744/Universal-Remote-Control-with-PDA
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9efe622c-06ec-4822-bf4f-e85f867f1504/c-ir-communication-between-ppc6700-and-tvdvdht-receiver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are just searching for the codes, [here](http://www.remotecentral.com/cgi-bin/codes) you can find a lot of them, with a lot of manufacturers.